# Jquery binding on a string?

Tags: jquery, binding, modernizr

I am at loss trying to understand this piece of code:

```
$s_middle.on(this.transEndEventName, function(event) {

       //Do stuff        

 });
```

$smiddle holds some html:

```
<div class="myclass">...</div>
```

And `this.transEndEventName` holds whatever prefix modernizr returns plus the class .block

```
this.transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[Modernizr.prefixed('transition')] + '.block';
```

So what's "on" binding? A string?

If i consoled.log this.transEndEventName I get:

```
transitioned.block
```

The code seems to execute after the transition inside  `$s_middle` is done. But I don't understand why.

Can someone explain how this works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) api in jQuery takes a string as the name of the event to listen to, and a function to execute when that event happens. The first argument is always a string.

`transitionEnd` is an event that can prefixed (e.g. `webkitTransitionEnd`, `mozTransitionEnd`, etc). Whoever wrote this is using Modernizr to bind to the proper event in whichever browser runs the code.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. I did not realize that "transiotionEnd" was a valid event.

Comment: well, "transitionEnd" is a valid event ;)